# js: true - how to keep the browser running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

When I do `js: true` test (rspec+capybara+selenium) it runs the browser and all steps are visible. I wish to be able to stop in some point and look around the page. Is there a way to do that? For non `js: true` tests `save_and_open_page` from `gem launchy` works well but here it's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is better than putting a `sleep` or a debugger breakpoint where you want to stop, then you can look around the page.

Also note that your browser will be loaded by capybara without extensions, so you cannot use firebug or other tools (but perhaps the native developer tools of firefox remain available I'm not sure)

Comment: It's a shame that it's without firebug. Should be a way to change that too. I even tried adding `binding.pry` before but it didn't worked for me. Now I see this was because test failed before that line. `sleep` works as well.

Comment: Try looking at this article to use firebug with capybara, I never tried though http://waltersmith.us/articles/using-firebug-with-capybara